# Capture card interference

Tags: graphics-card, video-capture, capture, interference

I get a consistent pattern of interference on Windows 7 64 bit on composite video input on a variety of capture cards, graphics cards and even motherboard combinations.

The cards are the Compro VideoMate C100 and the SAA7130 Analog TV Card. I've tried various Nvidia GT220 and GT440 cards.

Is it possible to fix this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Silly question - have you tried different cables?  A different input source?

Comment: Good question, I've got a higher quality phono here so I'll try it and another camera

Comment: Same problem with different camera and cable.

Comment: Unless it's an incompatibility with either A: your software or B: the driver those video cards are using (or C: those two things don't play nicely together), I have no clue.  You've ruled out a hardware problem anywhere along the line.

Comment: I suspect the capture cards use the same chip which is getting interference from the graphics card but I dont know/

Comment: Update: it has nothing to do with the graphics card, I took that out and the same problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Compro VideoMate C100, with several large flashing green lines continuously streaked across the screen. It was nothing to do with the input cables, as the interference was showing even with no cables plugged in.

I think it was caused by a driver update. I rolled back the driver to version 1.3.8.2 - also available here: http://www.comprousa.com/en/download/video_capture.html?d=1&p=c100

I still get the occasional faint grey line, but not enough to worry about.